# Regex for fixed number of letters with space inbetween

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to have a regex that filters string in which only 4 letters and if needed a space inbeween, followed by 4 letters again and so on is acceptable.

```
OK: 
abcd efgh ijkl mnop
aasd asdd
asda

Not OK:
abcsd asda
asd asdd asdd
asdd asdd asdds
asdd  asdd  asds
```

So far I can match just first 4 letter word with space or without.

```
^(| )[a-z\s]{0,4}$(| )
```

So this fails after I add a character or another space as e.g.  `asdf s <- fails.`
What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Is a leading and/or trailing space allowed? Should the empty string be a match?

Comment: `(| )` is much better expressed as a space followed by a question mark, where `?` means the preceding token is optional. It makes no sense to have anything after `$` since it matches the end-of-line. Yours happens to match, since one of the options is 0-width, but just remove everything after `$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern that you tried matches an optional space at the start and at the end an can match 0-4 times a char a-z or a whitespace char and could possibly also match an empty string as everything is optional.

The pattern could be matching 4 times a-z and repeat 0+ times a space followed by 4 times a-z

```
^[a-z]{4}(?: [a-z]{4})*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vWhDEG/1)

**Note** that in the first line `ijklm` is 5 chars instead of 4 and `\s` could possibly also match a newline.

Comment: Thank you for explanation aswell!